Can the enable line on a linear regulator be toggled at high frequencies?
For linear regulators with an enable pin what are the implications for toggling the EN pin to modulate the output at frequencies around 200Hz?
I was thinking of using the second regulator on the FeatherS2 board to power some miniature Christmas lights (LED, around 80mA at 3V) and using the EN control via the ESP32-S2's GPIO21 to modulate the brightness with PWM. The regulator is an OnSemi NCP167. The only relevant entry I've found so far in the datasheet is a turn-on time of 120us which is fine for 200Hz but would prevent use of higher frequencies. I see an interesting note in Can a linear regulator be cycled on and off repeatedly without damage? about potential issues with low (0.1Hz) frequencies).
I realise an external transistor is the typical solution here, I'm only doing this for experimentation and fun. I've had a look at the voltage output on a 'scope and it looks like a nice square wave with the effects of the 1uF capacitor on the output.

You say "at high frequencies", then you say "200 Hz"; which is it?

It's 200Hz, for the context of an enable line on a regulator I've decided this is "high".

If you already tried it, and it appeared to work as well when toggled on/off at 200 Hz, what implications are you after?

watch out for generated EMI/RFI ...

Only experience will tell. Linear regulators aren't designed with this kind of thing in mind, and their datasheets probably don't address this use-case. Since you are experimenting, you'll probably have better experience with this idea than 99% of people here, and will be better positioned to answer your own question. That said, here are some thoughts:
The quoted 120μs turn-on time is actually the time it takes for the output to rise to 95% of its final value, and those figures are worst-case, conditional upon output capacitance \$C_{OUT}=1\mu F\$. The rise will no doubt begin less than a microsecond following the enable signal, and continue "slowly" upwards, arriving at its final value after some time determined chiefly by \$C_{OUT}\$. Not great for PWM.
\$C_{OUT}\$ may or may not be 1μF in your case. The board probably already has \$C_{OUT}\$ installed. Page 7 of the datasheet recommends a minimum of \$C_{OUT}=0.7\mu F\$ to guarantee stability over a wide temperature range, 1μF is about right. If the regulator were to power something other than LEDs, then you might have decoupling capacitors scattered around which exceed 1μF total, but since you have only LEDs in mind, you should be fine with 1μF.
The regulator contains circuitry to actively discharge \$C_{OUT}\$ when the enable signal is not asserted, which effectively places a 280Ω resistance across the load and \$C_{OUT}\$. The rate at which \$C_{OUT}\$ discharges will depend on the combined impedance of the LED load and this 280Ω resistance. With no load, time to discharge (to 5%) would be a little under \$5RC\$:
$$ 5 \times 280\Omega \times 1\mu F = 1.4ms $$
That's much slower than the rise time of 120μs, and far exceeds the pulse times you would expect from a 200Hz PWM signal. You have no hope of operating this regulator with PWM under a light load. To obtain a similar discharge time, the load would have to draw extra current from \$C_{OUT}\$, roughly:
$$ I \approx \frac{CV}{t} = \frac{1\mu F \times 3V}{120\mu s} = 25mA $$
That's assuming constant load current from \$C_{OUT}\$, which obviously isn't the case, it's just a ballpark figure to obtain some idea of the load requirements. It might be better to install a permanent load resistance (in addition to the LEDs) to obtain similar discharge time:
$$ R_{DISCHARGE} = \frac{120\mu s}{5 \times 1\mu F} = 24\Omega $$
This would draw current (and power):
$$ I = \frac{3V}{24\Omega} = 125mA $$
$$ P = \frac{V^2}{R} = \frac{3^2}{24\Omega} = 0.38W $$
Not ideal, but these are the kind of things you'll have to consider. Also, I've assumed everywhere that the regulator output is about 3V, you'll have to adjust the calculations to suit.
At 200Hz, using 8-bit PWM with 256 distinct levels of duty-cycle, each pulse could be as short as \$\frac{1}{200 \times 256} = 20\mu s\$. That's small compared to the rise/fall times discussed above, so you should expect very little control at low duty-cycles, bordering on guesswork.

Thanks. I gave it a go and it seems to work ok. There's a look at the output on an oscilloscope in my article Instructables: PWM Brightness Control of Small Christmas Lights Using Enable Feature on Voltage Regulator.
